# jQuery - do function THEN initiate mailto

Tags: jquery, mailto

Can anyone shed some light?

I'm building a site that has a little ribbon at the top to fire off a mailto. When the ribbon is clicked, I want it to bounce. Trouble is, the mailto: fires at the same time and the bounce effect of the ribbon is missed because of the email client window appearing over the site.

Is there a way of delaying the mailto action with jQuery - or adding the mailto via jQuery?

I've got the below so far… I've prevented the default action and the bounce is working - i just need the last bit of firing the mailto again.

Thank you in advance…

```
$(document).ready(function() {         
   $( "a#pullTag" ).click(function( event ) {
      event.preventDefault();
      doBounce($(this), 3, '10px', 100);   
   });
   function doBounce(element, times, distance, speed) {
      for(i = 0; i < times; i++) {
      element.animate({marginTop: '-='+distance},speed)
      .animate({marginTop: '+='+distance},speed);
      }        
   } 
});
```

HTML is simply:

```
 <a href="#" id="pullTag">Email Me</a>
```

Comment: Helo, where is mailTo ?

Comment: +10 from me ,Enjoy Sir :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do this :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("a#pullTag").click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        doBounce($(this), 3, '10px', 100);
    });

    function doBounce(element, times, distance, speed) {
        for (i = 0; i < times; i++) {
            element.animate({ marginTop: '-=' + distance }, speed)
                   /*
                   I have added a callback function to the last .animate()
                   This function checks the animation queue length
                   When the last animation is reached (queue length == 1),
                   it changes the current URL to the link's [href] attribute
                   */
                   .animate({ marginTop: '+=' + distance }, speed, function() {
                        if (element.queue().length <= 1) {
                            window.location = element.prop('href');
                        }
                    });
        }
    }
});
```

[**You can view a JSFiddle demo here**](http://jsfiddle.net/wBNYu/2/)

Comment: +1 I have done something quite similar will post for reference.

Comment: should be the "winning" answer

Comment: Sorry - thought I had marked it as 'helpful' rather than 'winning' answer

Comment: And this one is the one that helped - changed the document.location to window.location.href = "mailto:xxx@xxx"; and it worked fine. thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Using a callback to the last animate function you can modify your doBounce to call when all animations are complete.

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("a#pullTag").click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var href = $(this).attr('href');
        doBounce($(this), 3, '10px', 1000, href);
    });

    function doBounce(element, times, distance, speed) {
        element.animate({
            marginTop: '-=' + distance
        }, speed)
            .animate({
            marginTop: '+=' + distance
        }, speed, 'swing', function () {
            times = times - 1;
            if (times === 0) {
                console.log('animation complete, redirecting to href');
                window.location.href = element.attr('href');
            } else {
                console.log('animation not yet complete');
                doBounce(element, times, distance, speed);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Demo here http://jsfiddle.net/hPWMw/1/

Comment: +1 : same idea, better than the accepted answer since it actually waits for the animation to end.

Comment: Yeh! I agree, accepted answer is no better than original predicament?!

Answer (score 0):

Try to use (to fire mailto event via jQuery):

```
window.location.href = "mailto:address@dmail.com";
```

So in your code it can look like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {         
   $( "a#pullTag" ).click(function( event ) {
      event.preventDefault();
      doBounce($(this), 3, '10px', 100);   
      window.location.href = "mailto:address@dmail.com";
   });
   function doBounce(element, times, distance, speed) {
      for(i = 0; i < times; i++) {
      element.animate({marginTop: '-='+distance},speed)
      .animate({marginTop: '+='+distance},speed);
      }        
   } 
});
```

**[JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/KmU3Y/)**

Comment: Can u give jsfiddle ?

Comment: This will fire the window to the `mailto` address immediately whilst the animations are still happening or even only just beginning?!

Comment: @RobSchmuecker this will call `doBounce()` function, then fire `mailto` event

Comment: `doBounce` will queue the animations, but it will not wait until they finish. The `mailto` will be called event before the first animation ends.

Comment: @pes502 Open your fiddle which I have modified here for clarity with a web-inspector console like chrome dev-tools or firebug to see what I mean.  http://jsfiddle.net/KmU3Y/1/